# Why are static members and static constant members different in initialization?

Tags: c++, static, initialization, constexpr

```
class Test
{
private:
    static int data;
public:
    static constexpr int MAX{ 10 }; // OK
public:
    int getData() const { return data; }
    void setData(int rhs) { data = rhs; }
};

int Test::data{};
```

I have code like above.
Why are static members and static constant members different in initialization?
Is it just a difference in grammar?

Comment: You could do `static inline int data{};` if you want to initialize `data` *in situ*.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in C++17, `constexpr` implies `inline`, allowing in-line definitions with initialisers. A more fair comparison would be with `static inline int data{};`, which looks the same.

A `constexpr` variable has to have an initialiser (presumably so it can be used in constant expressions). Before C++17, this means that you have to write:

```cpp
class Test
{
private:
    static int data;
public:
    static constexpr int MAX{ 10 };
public:
    int getData() const { return data; }
    void setData(int rhs) { data = rhs; }
};

constexpr int Test::MAX;
int Test::data{};
```

to be able to ODR-use `MAX` (essentially "take the address of"/"bind a reference to") since `inline` static data members didn't exist. This is also similar for `constexpr` and non-`constexpr` static data members.